# SG3525 Working and experimentation

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, feedback

I was trying to understand the SG3525A (from ST-Micro) working. So I built a circuit as shown below. I read various articles on this chip, it mentions that to know whether its working or not, it can be checked using the Ct pin which would show the Sawtooth wave.

[image: SG3525]

In this circuit, I have the following questions.

1. The Vref pin is supposed to provide a 5V precision reference. Its not detectable in the oscilloscope. Is it normal?
2. <strike>What is the maximum input voltage that can be given to each pin.</strike>
3. In many reference circuits I found that the compensation pin is connected with a series capacitor and a resistor and it is fed to the inverting input. Why is it done and how is the values of capacitor and resistor is selected?
4. What is the work of the oscillator pin? Am I supposed to see square wave in the scope with the set frequency using RC?

Please help me out in finding the answers. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you read the data sheet?

Comment: Yes. I did read the datasheet.

Comment: 1. What’s your Vcc? Does it require minimum load on Vref? 2. Read the datasheet. 3. Google compensation network/read the application note. 4. Read the datasheet.

Comment: The DS tells you the max voltages - are you sure you read it?

Comment: @Andyaka I read the datasheet. Overlooked the specs. My mistake.. I was supposed to get the 5v output out of the Vref pin. But I'm not getting any signal from any pins of the chip.

Comment: @winny The Vcc is 12v referred to as Vc in the diagram.. I tried understanding the compensation network from google but didn't quite get it with respect to my design.. I'm trying to build a boost converter using sg3525 so wanted to try out the bare chip and understand the working from the base.. Sorry if my questions are lame.. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: No that's fine. Your question does however not show any reaseach effort, which is frowned upon here. If you have Vcc and EN/SHDN in the correct position, you should have Vref. Some obscure PWM ICs does require a minimum load on the Vref. Oh! And capacitor on Vref!

Comment: @winny I tried out different circuit configurations on different chips. I posted one of the configuration here. As you said, I tried out adding a cap between Vref pin and Gnd, and a 10K resistor. No reference potential is showing up.

Comment: You need to tie SHDN! to Vcc, not ground via your 1k resistor.

Comment: Have you saw this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356098/help-understanding-how-to-use-a-sg3525/356126#356126

Comment: @winny According to datasheet from stm, the shutdown pin is active high..so making it high would shutdown the chip..  anyways I tried doing that too.. didn't work..

Comment: Yes @G36.. I already read that article.. that is where I got the idea about the sawtooth wave..

Comment: So, you do not have a 5V at Vref? Also, you should connect pin 9 (Comp) together with pin 1(INV). Also, try adding some load resistance (1k) at OUTa and OUTB

Comment: @G36 Did everything you mentioned.. tried directly connecting comp pin to inv(voltage follower configration) also. And yes I also did add 10k resistor at both the outputs .. nothing happens.. are there any other troubleshooting steps please ? Your answer in the previous article helped me a lot in understanding the IC.. as you said there.. I couldn't even see any sawtooth wave at the Ct pin also.

Comment: Well, in that case, you have a damage IC or a fake one. Or you did somewhere a stupid error in assembly. Are you using the breadboard ?

Comment: @G36 Yes. I'm using a breadboard.

Comment: @G36 you were right. The IC was indeed damaged. The CT pin is giving out sawtooth waveform now.  Thank you for all of your help.
I'm now experimenting on how to vary duty cycle using simple potentiometer.

Comment: Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

To help people like me who are wrestling first time with this SG3525 IC, I'm sharing the answers to the above questions.

1. "The Vref pin is supposed to provide a 5V precision reference. Its not detectable in the oscilloscope. Is it normal?"

Ans : The IC was damaged. With any SG3525 IC you are supposed to get 5V reference output from the Vref pin (16th pin) detectable using multimeter/oscilloscope

2. "What is the maximum input voltage that can be given to each pin."

Ans: The maximum input voltage to each pin is 5v unless otherwise specified. For eg. V+ and Vc pin accepts upto 35v.

3. "In many reference circuits I found that the compensation pin is connected with a series capacitor and a resistor and it is fed to the inverting input. Why is it done and how is the values of capacitor and resistor is selected?"

Ans. The compensation pin is actually the output of the error amplifier. So any change in input would almost instantaneously changes the output of the error amplifier. So to avoid those sudden changes normally RC series or parallel circuit is fedback to the Inverting pin of the Error amplifier (Pin-1).

Some more **points** to note for **beginners**.

- The **maximum duty ratio** of SG3525 is **50%**. So if you want to run the IC standalone as an oscillator with 50% duty. Just connect Vref to Pin-2 and enjoy squrewave output with 50% duty.
- If you want to use this IC to drive mosfet using an optocouplor such as TLP250H, and the output squarewave must be of 5v, just connect 5v to the Vc pin (Pin-13) then you would see a square wave with 5v peak.

I'm still trying to understand the proportional change in duty ratio using feedback. If anyone is already an expert please share your experience.

Thank you