# Voltage to PWM Circuit, need to understand frequency

Tags: pwm

This is an off shelf component that might fit my need. Unfortunately the documentation is terrible. It should convert a 0-5v or 0-10v analog to PWM (0-5v/0-10v is a jumper). The analog voltage signal controls the duty cycle. The potentiometer controls "Precision" per the description. I think they mean it can offset the duty cycle from the control signal. I don't care about that, I can program the control signal. This should be perfect for me if the PWM frequency is 21-28KHz.

I can't find/get any info about the frequency.  It was cheap enough that I picked one up and started mapping out the traces. I've been trying to learn for a few hours now and I can't quite figure it all out. I think the 555 is controlling the frequency, but this doesn't look like any examples I have found. I want to know specifically which resistors/capacitor are controlling frequency and what it calculates to. I have the ability to rework the board and change them if needed. I don't have an oscilloscope right now, but I'm working on borrowing one. I'm hoping to figure this out and get any possibly needed components before I borrow the scope.

The picture should show connections, sorry if it is ugly. I will gladly clarify anything if confusing.  FYI, I just used purple when it would cross over another red line.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the 555 is being used as a ramp signal generator and the LM393 compares the analog Vin (after jumper & trimpot) to the 555's ramp. Q1, R6, R8, etc probably form a constant(ish) current source to charge the 555's timing cap (probably C2) in order to make a nice straight ramp.

Comment: `21-28KHz` ....  you should be able to use the audio input of your computer and an audio recorder such as Audacity to display the waveform   https://www.audacityteam.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit will look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPSMju.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Help understanding how to use a SG3525](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356098/help-understanding-how-to-use-a-sg3525/356126#356126)

And the PWM frequency will depend on \$C_2\$ and \$R_6\$ values.

\$Q_1\$ together with \$R_6 , D_2 , D_3\$ forms a constant current source.

And this current will be around \$I_S = \frac{0.66V}{R_6} = 140\mu\textrm{A} 
\$

And this current will charge the \$C_2\$ capacitor. And if the voltage across the capacitor reaches the NE555 threshold value (2/3 Vsup). The 555 will quickly discharge the capacitor to 1/3Vsup.

So, the equation for PWM frequency will look like this

\$\Large F \approx \frac{3 \cdot I_S}{C_2 \cdot V_+}  \$

So for 5V supply, as you have in your circuit the equation becomes

\$\Large F \approx 0.6 \cdot\frac{I_S}{C_2}  \$

> I'm trying to simplify all the resistors and jumper leading to U2+
>   (R9,R10,R1,R3,R4). Suppose I don't need the option to jumper to a 0-5V
>   input and only using 0-10V input. Also would like to eliminate
>   adjustability with R1. From testing I know that for best function R1
>   is set at 8k Ohm between jumper above R3, and 94k Ohm to ground below
>   R3.

In theory, this voltage divider at the input should do the job:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the great info so far. Follow up with request of application info. The VCC will be 5V, but the VAnalog signal will be 0-10V (with jumper in 10v position). The 0-10V analog signal is coming from an aquarium controller. I can program it to change signal voltage (0-10V) based on tank temperature, pH, etc. The result of the PWM should be 5V modulated at Fout. This will signal a good 4-pin PC type fan for ventilation. It runs at 12V but uses a 5V PWM for speed. Advice was based on 5V supply, does that mean VCC, or signal? I didn't mention VCC (sorry), does this info change formula?

Comment: @Diznaster  V+ is the internal voltage provided by AMS1117. And this voltage will be equal to around 5V it should be within this region 4.9V...5.1V.

Comment: Sorry It's been a while, other stuff...  I measured the frequency at 55kHz (I also got a response of "around 50kHz" from seller).  So if I understand correctly C2 is probably about 1.5nF.  I'm going to remove it and measure it.  If confirmed then a replacement of 3.3nF should get me around the desired 25kHz?

Comment: @Diznaster You will never know for sure until you change the C2 and measured the output frequency.

Comment: I removed C2, measured it and replaced it with close to what was calculated for desired frequency.  It worked as expected and I could just quit, but I still want to learn a few things and try to simulate.  The 0-5v/0-10v part of the circuit with the jumper is confusing to me.  Could you show a version with only 0-10v.  Also I will need values for diodes 1-3, if you can offer any baseline guess on those.  I'm honestly reading a lot, using datasheets, and learning, not just asking for answers handed to me.  I like to see the answer and figure out how you got to it.

Comment: @Diznaster D1 is an ordinary green LED. Not needed in the simulation. D2, D3 is the 1N4148 type or any "signal diode" you have. As for the jumper. Simply connect via wire the upper part of the R10 resistor together with 0...5V input. Do you understand this?

Comment: Yes, Thanks.  I realized the D1 was an LED, Duh!

Comment: Hopefully my last question!  I'm trying to simplify all the resistors and jumper leading to U2+ (R9,R10,R1,R3,R4).  Suppose I don't need the option to jumper to a 0-5V input and only using 0-10V input.  Also would like to eliminate adjustability with R1.  From testing I know that for best function R1 is set at 8k Ohm between jumper above R3, and 94k Ohm to ground below R3.  I'm trying to rationalize all the parallel resistance.  I'm guessing it has a lot to do with options and adjustment.  I'd like to understand how to make it simpler with less components.

Comment: @Diznaster I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, I was thinking that was all a means to make a voltage divider.  Your edit helps me to understand (at least I think I do). It brings the 0-10v into the range of approximately 1.6v-3.3v.  Then the comparator can adjust the duty cycle based on when the rising sawtooth crosses the switching threshold.

Comment: I modified the circuit as described, but it didn't quite work out.  Now the duty cycle is only adjustable from 50-100%.  At 10V=99%, 9V=96%, 8V=90%, 7V=84%, 6V=79%, 5V=74%, 4V=68%, 3V=63%, 2V=56%, 0V=47%.  Before it was close to 0-100% and each 1V+ was a 10% increase in duty cycle.  My guess is that it has something to do with R2 connecting to 5V+ in the new simplification theory. Before that the complicated (to me) divider/adjustment circuit was not tied to 5V+.The 0-10V is an independent source.  Or maybe I just need to tweak some resistance values, if so which should I adjust/how much?

Comment: @Diznaster Can you measure via scope the voltage at U2 inverter input? And what did you use as a C2 capacitor?

Comment: Unfortunately not with a scope.  It is 1.719v to the IN- pin of U2 from the Tresh pin of the 555.  This is with the circuit configured back to the original format using R9,R10,R1,R3,R4.  C2 was changed from 1nF to 2.2nF to get frequency from about 50kHz to 23kHz.  With the new divider it seemed to somewhat work, but the 0-10v input would not drop below around 2v at IN+ on U2 even with it completely disconnected.  So I was thinking it was because the divider was now tied to 5V+ and it wasn't before.  I'll think on it more, any other ideas let me know I really appreciate the help

Comment: I put a divider on only the 0-10v signal (not tied to 5v+).  It got me closer.  It didn't get quite what was calculated and I'm thinking that is because other resistors are also dividing.  I did some testing with different values and re-calculating the divider. I'm fairly confident I have something that works now and I understand how to adjust the resistance values.  So I don't think I need anymore help on this. I'll report back in a few days, I need to tidy up the mods and also do some other stuff with the kids.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that C2 = 10nF and Regulator output is 5Vdc
140uA will flow on C2 which will raise the voltage at a rate of 14000 volts per second.
If Vcc is 5Vdc (at the regulator output) the 555 will threshold at 3,33V and retrigger at 1.66V. C2 voltage travel is then 1.66V = 1/3 of Vcc
This will take 1.66/14000= 119uSec
or a free running frequency of 1/119uS = 8.4 kHz.
Any change is C2 value or regulator Voltage will inversely change the frequency.
Double C2, Fout will be half, double Vcc Fout will be half (because Q1 collector current is independent of Vregulator).

Your best bet is to measure the output frequency when your analog Vin 
is at 1/2 Vcc(measure it).
Then change C2 accordingly. Some caution about this simple relation: Check your output impedance. If the output is connected to a load that is near the 2.2k R5 and or is capacitive or inductive you may endup with erratic behavior.

It would have been usefull if we knew what this circuit would be utilized for, along with a little more details about the output driving what ?  Bottom line C2 is your target for Fout adjustment. Good success with your project :)